# Make a hamburger ID work in two headers

Tags: javascript, header, onscroll

I am creating a clone of the header and when the scroll reach a certain height, the clone version will display.  This works, as I want. The problem is that I am trying to get the “hamburger” action to work in both headers. Now it only works in first section. I need to get it working in section two also. I know I have used an ID (“trigger-overlay”), which should only be used one time and be unique.

Is this correct and the reason why it is not working? Do you guys know a workaround to fix this problem?

I need it to be an ID because of a more complex code in another script, but if it’s not possible to keep it I will do it in another way. I appreciate any help here. [See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfbq2b0k/3/)

**HTML**

```
<section id="one">
    <header class=""> <a id="trigger-overlay" class=""><span class="hamburger"></span></a>
    </header>
</section>
<section id="two"></section>
```

**CSS**

```
section {
    height:100vh;
}

#one{
    background-color:#0097a7;
}

#two{
    background-color:#00bcd4;
}

.hamburger, #trigger-overlay .hamburger:before, #trigger-overlay .hamburger:after {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:#80deea;
    width:25px;
    height:3px;
    display:block;
    border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-transition:top 0.3s 0.2s ease, bottom 0.3s 0.2s ease, background-color 0.3s ease, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
    transition:top 0.3s 0.2s ease, bottom 0.3s 0.2s ease, background-color 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
}
#trigger-overlay {
    float: left;
    margin-left:15px;
}
.hamburger:before, .hamburger:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
}
.hamburger {
    position:relative;
    top:19px;
}
.hamburger:before {
    top:-7px;
}
.hamburger:after {
    bottom:-7px;
}
/*Hamburger hover*/
 #trigger-overlay .hamburger:hover, #trigger-overlay .hamburger:hover:before, #trigger-overlay .hamburger:hover:after {
    background-color: #00838f;
}
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#00acc1;
}
header.clone {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #00acc1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: 0.2s transform cubic-bezier(.3, .73, .3, .74);
}
body.down header.clone {
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

**Vanilla JS**

```
var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' );

var sticky = {
    sticky_after: 200,
    init: function () {
        this.header = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0];
        this.clone = this.header.cloneNode(true);
        this.clone.classList.add("clone");
        this.header.insertBefore(this.clone, this.header.childNodes[1]);
        this.scroll();
        this.events();
    },
    scroll: function () {
        if (window.scrollY > this.sticky_after) {
            document.body.classList.add("down");

        } else {
            document.body.classList.remove("down");
        }
    },
    events: function () {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scroll.bind(this));
    }
};

function toggleOverlay() {
    alert("I want to be active in both headers ");
}


triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", sticky.init.bind(sticky));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately just using the same ID won't give you the same EventListeners. But, it's easy to get around your problem by simply adding the same EventListeners to the newly created clone:

```
   document.getElementsByClassName('clone')[0].addEventListener('click', toggleOverlay);
```

See a working version of your Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qfbq2b0k/4/